# Access $scope from html?

Tags: angularjs

Because of stupid third-party reasons, I need to access $scope from the html.

This is what I'm attempting:

```
<html ng-app>
    <!-- head goes here-->
    <body>
        <!--Body goes here-->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            console.log($scope);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you provide some code?

Comment: I forgot to mark the code as code, sorry!

Comment: This was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34416935/access-dynamic-scope-variable-inside-html

Answer (score 16):

Because `angular` is exposed globally, you can use:

```
var scope = angular.element().scope()
```

For example if you have this in your markup

```
<div ng-controller="someCtrl" id="someId">{{test}}</div>
```

You can access the isolated scope of the controller `someCtrl` like this:

```
var scope = angular.element($("#someId")).scope()
scope.test = "Hello, world!";
```

(you might want to $apply the scope as well, see [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope))

Comment: I manage to access angular.element on this element ´<div ng-controller="Invite" id="invite" class="invite">´ but scope.scope does not exist.

Answer (score 3):

Just use 'this'... it is a reference that points to the controller scope