# Access dynamic $scope variable inside html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

I'm creating a large amount of directives and all will include dynamic scope variables that will be initialised inside the link functions
**e.g:**

```
//
link: function(scope, ele, attr){
  scope.key = scope.somevar + 'something_else';
  scope[scope.key] = 'the_value';
}
//
```

I want to access the value in the templates of the directives via`scope.key`.

```
<div ng-if="scope[key]"> something </div>
```

Currently I only see it been viable through a function call like so:

**html**

```
<div ng-if="scope(key)"> something </div>
```

**js**

```
scope.scope = function(key) {
  return scope[key];
}
```

But then the problem is I will need to copy this into all the directives.

Another option I considered was to assign the getter function onto the `$rootScope` making it globally accessible but how do I bind it to or pass in the current directives scope. (If even possible).

**What would be a good approach to this?**

Comment: `scope[key]` doesn't work because you don't have a scope object on the scope. Try `ng-if="keyContainer[key]"` and having `scope.keyContainer = {}; scope.keyContainer[scope.key] = *val*`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Inside of Angular template `this` keyword points to the current evaluation context, i.e. current scope. It means that you would be able to achieve what you are after by using bracket notation on the `this` object:

```
<div ng-if="this[key]"> something </div>
```

Comment: I hang my head in shame for not trying `this`. Pardon the pun. Thank you!

Comment: Using `this` it's very dangerous, because some directives creates a own scope.  The better way it's use the 'controllerAs' syntax.

Comment: @GonzaloPincheiraArancibia I would agree with you that controllerAs is generally better choice for many things. However, the point of the question was how to access dynamic scope property.

Answer (score 2):

Use `bindToController` option in your directive

JS

```
bindToController: true,
controller: 'MyController',
controllerAs: 'ctrl',
link: function(scope, ele, attr){
  scope.ctrl.key = scope.somevar + 'something_else';
  scope.ctrl[scope.ctrl.key] = 'the_value';
}
```

HTML

```
<div ng-if="ctrl[ctrl.key]"> something </div>
```

Check this codepen as example: http://goo.gl/SMq2Cx

Comment: Thanks for the insight, I wasn't aware you could do this.

Comment: ControllerAs is indeed would be good idea. However, not the way you use it in your example. You don't want to have controller alias in link function. bindToController is the way to go in this case.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to see all your code, but it sounds like you could just create a function on your scope to retrieve the value:

```
scope.getValue = function() {
    return scope[scope.key];
}
```

Then in your HTML:

```
<div ng-if="getValue()"> something </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however you have just duplicated what I've provided in the question just replacing the names.

Comment: sorry.. that scope.scope was a little confusing.